# $f$ is surjective iff $f|_U$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is surjective if and only if there exists a finite dimensional subspace U ⊆ V such that $f|_U:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is surjective. Where $f$ is defined as:

$f(v) = (f_1(v),...,f_n(v))$

I already proved the $\Leftarrow$ dimention but I am having trouble proving the $\Rightarrow$ direction.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is $V$ and what is $f$? In particular, is $f$ linear and is $V$ infinite dimensional?

Comment: $f$ is a linear map, $f_i \in V^*$ and $V$ is a finite vector space

Comment: You should edit the question and include this information there. If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, then the other direction is trivial: take $U=V$. The problem is more interesting when $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n \in \mathbb R^n$ be the standard basis (any basis will do).  As $f$ is surjective we can choose $v_i \in V$ such that $f(v_i) = e_i$.  Then define $U$ to be the span of the $v_i$.